# $2^\kappa-\kappa=2^\kappa$ for infinite $\kappa$ without the AC

Tags: cardinals

Without using the AC, show that if $\kappa \geq \aleph_0$ then $2^{\kappa}-\kappa=2^{\kappa}$. That is to say, for such $\kappa$ there is a unique cardinal $\mu$ such that $\kappa+\mu=2^{\kappa}$, and this $\mu$ equals $2^{\kappa}$.

In Rubin & Rubin, "Equivalents of the Axiom of Choice", 2nd edition, 1985, this is mentioned as a well-known property of cardinals (cf. Theorem 0.14.f in the book), but sadly they do not provide a proof.

Found a proof for the case $\kappa=2\kappa$.

**Lemma**: for any cardinals $\kappa,\mu,\lambda$, if $\kappa+\mu=\lambda=\lambda^{2}$ then either there is a surjection of $\kappa$ onto $\lambda$, or we have $\mu=\lambda$.

**Proof**: if $f:\kappa\sqcup\mu\to\lambda^{2}$ is a bijection (with $\sqcup$ denoting disjoint union), let $g:\kappa\to\lambda$ be the map $\pi_1\circ (f\upharpoonright\kappa)$, where $\pi_{1}:\lambda^{2}\to\lambda$ is the projection on the first factor (i.e. $\pi_{1}(x,y)=x$ for $x,y\in\lambda$). If $g$ is surjective, we are done. If not, $\exists{z\in\lambda}$ such that $(\{z\}\times\lambda)\cap f[\kappa]=\varnothing$. But then we have $\{z\}\times\lambda\subseteq f[\mu]$, since f is a surjection, and so $\lambda\leq\mu$; since $\mu\leq\lambda$ also holds, we find $\mu=\lambda$, q.e.d.

Now if $\kappa+\mu=2^{\kappa}$, for a $\kappa$ with $\kappa=2\kappa$, apply the Lemma with $\lambda=2^{\kappa}$; one has $\lambda=\lambda^{2}$ in view of $\kappa=2\kappa$, and a surjection of $\kappa$ onto $\lambda=2^{\kappa}$ cannot exist (Cantor). It follows that $\mu=2^{\kappa}$.

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as saying that the cardinality of the powerset is strictly greater than the cardinality of the set itself.

Comment: @Alephnull I'm not very good at transfinite math, but isn't it possible to have a cardinal $\mu$ such that $\kappa < \mu < 2^{\kappa}$? (strict inequalities down the line). I think one needs to show that such a $\mu$ cannot satisfy the equation.

Comment: @Alephnull: this means that if $f:\kappa \to 2^{\kappa}$ is an injection, not only is the complement $2^{\kappa}-ran(f)$ non-empty, as you mention, but the entire power set $2^{\kappa}$ can be embedded in the complement.

Comment: @Alephnull Remember that we're working without choice here, so $\kappa<\mu$ doesn't imply that $\kappa+\mu=\mu$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Doesn't necessarily imply.

Comment: Well my intuition says that because 2^(alephnull)-(alephnull)=2^(alephnull) that this relationship shouldn't get better with larger aleph or beth numbers.

Comment: @Alephnull Not sure what you mean - there are models of ZF in which the implication fails. In colloquial speech, that's what "doesn't imply" means in this context. (And re: your next comment, where does the OP say that $\kappa$ is an $\aleph$ or $\beth$ number?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber In ZF, not a model of it. The axiom of choice is true in case you didn't know. By necessarily I meant not logically necessarily, although its true.

Comment: @Alephnull "The axiom of choice is true in case you didn't know." Based on what, exactly? I certainly don't accept it as true in the same way as Separation or Powerset for example, and I'm pretty dubious of the notion of "truth" in most mathematics in general. (Also, mathematicians do use "over $T$, $A$ doesn't imply $B$" to mean "$T$ doesn't prove "$A\implies B$" rather than "$T$ proves $\neg(A\implies B)$"; I'm following very standard usage here.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh yes you know what you are talking about. But I disagree; good day.

Comment: The independence of the AC ($@\aleph_0$) or the GCH (@Deepak) from ZF is without any doubt, and is quite irrelevant here. Can someone show that $\kappa+\mu=2^{\kappa} \to \mu = 2^{\kappa}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most difficult part would be to show that $2^\kappa \leq \mu$ if $\kappa + \mu = 2^\kappa =2 \times 2^\kappa$. It can be easily reduced to the following lemma:

**Lemma** Let $X$ be a set and $f \colon X \rightarrowtail 2 \times \mathcal{P}(X)$ be an injection, where $2 = \{0, 1\}$. Then there exists an injection $g \colon \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrowtail 2 \times \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}f$ and $\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}g$ are disjoint.

(Injectivity of $f$ is not necessary)

**Proof** Let $\pi_2 \colon 2 \times \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ be the right projection.

Define $g$ by
$$ g(A) = \begin{cases}
(1,A) & \text{if}\; (1, A) \notin \mathop{\mathrm{Im}} f \\
(0,\{ x \in X : x \notin \pi_2(f(x)) \;\text{xor}\; f(x)=(1,A) \}) & \text{if}\; (1, A) \in \mathop{\mathrm{Im}} f.
\end{cases} $$

Here $P \;\text{xor}\; Q$ means that $P$ but not $Q$, or $Q$ but not $P$.

(The intuition here is that we basically want to define $g(A) = (1, A)$. When it's impossible, then we want somewhere in $(0, -)$ to escape to. The existence of such a place is guaranteed by the diagonal argument, but we have to choose a different place for each collision. Xor-ing with $f(x)=(1, A)$ is the trick here: it embeds information about $y$ such that $f(y)=(1, A)$, while not disturbing the diagonal argument.)

$\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}f$ and $\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}g$ are disjoint. To show this, assume that $f(y) = g(A)$. If $(1, A) \notin \mathop{\mathrm{Im}} f$, then $f(y) = g(A) = (1, A)$. It contradicts with $(1, A) \notin \mathop{\mathrm{Im}} f$. If $(1, A) \in \mathop{\mathrm{Im}} f$, then $f(y) = (0, \mathop{-}) \neq (1, A)$. Thus
\begin{align*}
y \in \pi_2(f(y))
& \iff y \in \pi_2(g(A)) \\
& \iff y \in \pi_2((0,\{ x \in X : x \notin \pi_2(f(x)) \;\text{xor}\; f(x)=(1,A) \})) \\
& \iff y \in \{ x \in X : x \notin \pi_2(f(x)) \;\text{xor}\; f(x)=(1,A) \} \\
& \iff y \notin \pi_2(f(y)) \;\text{xor}\; f(y)=(1,A) \\
& \iff y \notin \pi_2(f(y))
\end{align*}
leads to contradiction. Therefore we never have $f(y) = g(A)$.

$g$ is injective. To show this, assume that $g(A) = g(A')$. Then either $(1, A), (1, A') \notin \mathrm{\mathop{Im}} f$ or $(1, A), (1, A') \in \mathrm{\mathop{Im}} f$. In the former case, we have $(1, A) = g(A) = g(A') = (1, A')$ and thus $A = A'$. In the latter case, take $y$ such that $f(y) = (1, A)$. Expanding $y \in \pi_2(g(A)) \iff y \in \pi_2(g(A'))$, we obtain
$$ y \notin \pi_2(f(y)) \;\text{xor}\; f(y) = (1, A) \iff y \notin \pi_2(f(y)) \;\text{xor}\; f(y) = (1, A')$$
and, since $\text{xor}$ is cancellative, we have
$$ f(y) = (1, A) \iff f(y) = (1, A'). $$
Since the left hand side is true, the right hand side is. Since $(1, A) = f(y) = (1, A')$, we have $A = A'$.

□

Thanks to alg_d (the author of the famous Japanese website about AC) for letting me know this interesting problem.

Comment: Wonderful proof, thanks Masaki!

Answer (score 3):

A proof of this theorem

> THEOREM $1$. We are able to prove without the aid of the axiom of choice that if $\mathfrak m$ is a cardinal number $\ge\aleph_0,$ then
>   $$2^\mathfrak m-\mathfrak m=2^\mathfrak m.$$

takes up most of pp. 172–173 in W. Sierpiński's book *Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers*, Second Edition Revised, 1963. Sierpiński uses the following lemma:

> LEMMA. If $\mathfrak m,\mathfrak p,\mathfrak s$ are cardinal numbers such that $2^\mathfrak m=\mathfrak m+\mathfrak p$ and $\mathfrak m=\mathfrak m+\mathfrak s,$ then $\mathfrak p\ge2^\mathfrak s.$

According to Sierpiński the theorem is due to A. Tarski, who stated it without proof in 1926; a proof was published by Sierpiński in: [W. Sierpiński, *Démonstration de l'égalité $2^\mathfrak m-\mathfrak m=2^\mathfrak m$ pour les nombres cardinaux transfinis,* Fund. Math. 34 (1947), 113—118.](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-fmv34i1p15)

Comment: Thanks a lot, bof!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it this way : 
$2^\kappa \leq 2^\kappa + \kappa \leq 2^\kappa + 2^\kappa \leq 2^\kappa \times 2 \leq 2^{\kappa+1}\leq 2^\kappa$

The first inequality comes from the natural injection, 
The second as well,where there is an injection $\kappa \to 2^\kappa$, sending $x\to \{x\}$
The third one comes from identifying the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$ as $A\times\{0\}\cup B\times\{1\}$
The fourth one is the natural injection,
And the last one is simply that, $\kappa$ being infinite, $\kappa +1 \leq \kappa$.

By Cantor-Bernstein's theorem, all these inequalities of cardinals (i.e. injections) can be turned into equalities of cardinals, that is, bijections.

Therefore $2^\kappa +\kappa \sim 2^\kappa$

Now if you take $A$ to be a subset of $2^\kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$, then you can use this bijection to produce a bijection $2^\kappa \setminus A\to 2^\kappa$.

EDIT : It seems Noah Schweber was quicker

Second edit: The last sentence of this answer is there to show the uniqueness of $\mu$: assume $\kappa + \mu = 2^\kappa$. Then the image of $\kappa$ under a bijection $\kappa + \mu \to 2^\kappa$ is a subset $A\subset 2^\kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$. But $2^\kappa\setminus A$ is the image of $\mu$ o has cardinality $\mu$. But according to my last sentence it also has cardinality $2^\kappa$, which proves that $2^\kappa \sim \mu$. I'm adding this to my answer because Matthé Van der Lee commented on Noah's answer saying that the uniqueness of $\mu$ hadn't been established.

Comment: Very good solution; makes sense. k=k+1    !

Comment: @Max: Sorry, I should have commented on this point earlier. This is precisely the difficulty with cardinal subtraction: its result may depend on how the smaller cardinal is embedded in the larger, and the result is generally not unique. If we have a bijection $f:B \to B\sqcup A$ (disjoint union) with $A\subseteq B$, there is no reason why $f[A]$ should be $A$ (the second summand in $B\sqcup A$) and $f[B-A]$ be $B$ (first summand). When $\kappa$ is embedded into $2^{\kappa}$ as the set of all singletons ($x\in\kappa\mapsto\{x\}$, thinking of $2^{\kappa}$ as the power set), --- continues below

Comment: it is not hard to see that the complement of the image is $\equiv 2^{\kappa}$, whereas this gets much harder when $\kappa$ is embedded in some unknown way.

So uniqueness of $\mu$ still remaines to be settled. (I have added a proof for the case $\kappa=2\kappa$ to the original question.)

Comment: But my edit precisely shows the uniqueness of $\mu$. I think you should read it again to see it

Comment: I'm afraid not. Please think again.

Comment: The $f:B \to B\sqcup A$ I'm talking about is your $f:2^{\kappa}+\kappa\equiv 2^{\kappa}$ (or the inverse, rather).

Comment: You say: "Now if you take $A$ to be a subset of $2^{\kappa}$ of cardinality $\kappa$, then you can use this bijection (say $f:2^{\kappa}\to 2^{\kappa}+\kappa$) to produce a bijection $g:2^{\kappa}-A\to 2^{\kappa}$." Please humour me and specify the bijection $g$.

Comment: Oh indeed, maybe I was bit quick in saying that. Let me think about it

Answer (score 0):

By contradiction: $2^\kappa-\kappa=[\kappa,2^\kappa)$. If $|[\kappa,2^\kappa)|<2^\kappa$ then, because $2^\kappa=[0,2^\kappa)=[0,\kappa)\cup[\kappa,2^\kappa)$, we must have $2^\kappa=|[0,\kappa)|=|\kappa|=\kappa$.

Comment: Wait, i think we need AC for this. Not so sure

Comment: Sugar baby love

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't drink and drive...

Comment: Lol, shouldn't drink and drive while commenting.

Comment: without choice, the cardinals are not linearly ordered, and if AC fails, there exist cardinals $\kappa,\lambda,\mu,\nu$ such that $\kappa < \lambda <\nu$ and $\kappa < \mu < \nu$ with $\lambda$ and $\mu$ incomparable (that is, neither $\lambda\leq\\mu$ nor $\mu\leq\lambda$. You can, if you like, still consider the interval $[0,2^{\kappa})$ of all cardinals $\geq 0$ and $< 2^{\kappa}$, but $[0,2^{\kappa})=[0,\kappa)\cup [\kappa.2^{\kappa})$ is no longer necessarily true: there could be a $\mu\le 2^{\kappa}$ with neither $\mu\le\kappa$ nor $\kappa\leq\mu$...

Comment: @Webmaster: **why is there a 5 minute time limit for editing comments?**

Comment: @MatthévanderLee Irrelevant to math.stackexchange. Try meta.stackexchange .